# Post array in ASP.NET MVC 2 using name="array_name[]" for form elements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, forms

Good day!

In PHP it is possible to assign name attribute to input elements with square brackets, like this: `name="my_value[]"` and PHP automagically converts this to array on server side.

Is this possible in ASP.NET MVC? If not is there any alternative to process a bunch of checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You might take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about the convention used by the default model binder.

Comment: Darin, thanks for the quick response, "one shot, one hit", as usual:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. @Darin Dimitrov, Very Helpful !

Comment: Is it possible for multidimensional array?

Answer (score 12):

Make sure the name is still the same, but go ahead and remove the brackets. You can then add the values to an array like so:

```
string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("my_value");
foreach (string value in values) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Courtesy of [link](http://www.aspnettricks.com/archives/requestform-get-values-for-fields-having-the-same-name/)

Comment: I was looking for Model binder solution, anyway this is a nice trick too.

Comment: Right on. I wanted to get this up for people looking for a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: @marcus for me `Request.Form.GetValues("my_value")` returns null but `Request.Form.GetValues("my_value[]")` returns the array of values, so it seems you need to keep the square brackets. +1 anways