# How to get data from model binder where form data has "[]" like "search[value]" in it?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC the modelbinder can bind the form data from the request from the client into parameters in the action of the controller.

In my case it's working with simple data like `draw`, `start` and `length`.
What do I need to write if I want to bind something with "[]" in it like `search[value]`?

[image]

My client code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")';
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "searching" : true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "type": "POST"
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "searchable": true },
            { "data": "name", "searchable": true }
        ]
    });
});
```

My server code:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string draw, int start, int length, string search)
{
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I managed to get the data this way, but I still think this work should be handle by the modelbinder.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string draw, int start, int length)
{
    var mySearcArray = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]");
    var mySearch = string.Empty;
    if (mySearcArray != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySearcArray[0]))
        {
            mySearch = mySearcArray[0];
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2
Ah, the Default ModelBinder only works on public Properties, so that's why the "magic" ain't happening. So it seems like you have two choices. Either Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]"); or make custom ModelBinder.

Comment: Are you trying to model bind Array?

Comment: Instead of search[value] why can't you set searchValue:s and receive it as parameter in action method?

Comment: @SivaGopal I think I'm not supposed to pass in manually. The datatable should handle it I think. But I tryed anyways. I pass the $('#example_filter input').val() to `data`, but it doesn't change it's value. I think it's because of the JavaScript Closure. I have tryed with a Date (time) too, and I always get the origional time on the server for each request.

Comment: Can you post the html binding as well which has search[value] etc., properties in it?

Comment: No I can't because it's handle in the datatable (datatable.net). Here is a link of the doc http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side. My picture is a list of all the Forms data datatable provide for each server-side request (from ordering, search, paging).

Comment: This might solve it the right way though: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871609/post-array-in-asp-net-mvc-2-using-name-array-name-for-form-elements 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699105/library-for-jquery-datatables-asp-net-mvc